# Как мне взять второй файл из коллекции в MongoDB с помощью питона

Tags: python, mongodb

имеется коллекция *instanceFile*

```
instanceFile = db.instanceFile
```

Я делаю запрос:

```
QUERY = {"primaryID": primaryID}
    obj = instanceFile.find(QUERY)
```

и мне нужно из obj достать именно 2ой по счету документ, как это можно сделать?

Так же интересно, как с помощью питона проверить количество документов в выборке. Пробовал count_documents - не получилось

Comment: в нативной Монге запрос выглядел бы так `db.test.find().skip(1).limit(1)`

Comment: блин, интересно эти методы работают в питоне или нет. Я бы сам затестил, но у меня сейчас нет доступа к БД.
Работяги, может кто знает, можно ли сделать что-то подобное в питоне?